# Entity framework update failure

Tags: entity-framework

I want to update a row in EF:

```
Case newCase = new Case(...);
dbContext.Entry(newCase).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

When updating I have this message:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0
>   row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were
>   loaded

There is no concurrency, since I am using the db on my machine.

If I go to SQL profiler to see the query that is executed, the  condition is:

```
WHERE [Id] = @p0 AND [RowVersion] = @p14;
```

in this condition, `@p0` is 1 and `@p14` is NULL, exactly like the record that I want to modify. however, if I manually launch this query in SQL Server after removing the `RowVersion` part of the query, it succeeds, updating 1 row.

What can be the problem and how can I solve it?

EDIT:

I tried to select the record just before updating it, but the error is the same:

```
    IEnumerable<Case> cases = from c in dbContext.Cases where c.Id.ToString() == "1" select c;
    Case cs = cases.SingleOrDefault();
    dbContext.Entry(cs).State = EntityState.Modified;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Here is the complete error:

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s)
>   but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted
>   since entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

And here is the query from Sql Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT OFF;

UPDATE [Case]
    SET 
        [Closed] = @p1
      , [Comment] = @p2
      , [ContactComment] = @p3
      , [ContactId] = @p4
      , [CreatedBy] = @p5
      , [CreatedDateTime] = @p6
      , [Description] = @p7
      , [Email] = @p8
      , [LastModifiedBy] = @p9
      , [LastModifiedDateTime] = @p10
      , [OpenedDateTime] = @p11
      , [Phone] = @p12
      , [RowVersion] = @p13
      , [SlaConsumedTime] = @p15
      , [SlaSuspended] = @p16
      , [SlaTotalTime] = @p17
      , [Status] = @p18
      , [Title] = @p19
WHERE 
    [Id] = @p0
    AND [RowVersion] = @p14;

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;',

N'@p0 int,@p1 bit,@p2 nvarchar(max) ,@p3 nvarchar(max) ,@p4 int,@p5 int,@p6 datetime2(7),
@p7 nvarchar(4000),@p8 nvarchar(4000),@p9 int,@p10 datetime2(7),@p11 datetime2(7),
@p12 nvarchar(max) ,@p13 varbinary(max) ,@p14 varbinary(max) ,@p15 time(7),@p16 bit,
@p17 time(7),@p18 int,@p19 nvarchar(4000)',
@p0=1,@p1=0,@p2=NULL,@p3=NULL,@p4=0,@p5=1,@p6='2015-09-23 09:07:55.7041023',@p7=N'y',
@p8=N't@f.f',@p9=1,@p10='2015-09-23 09:50:02.9934006',@p11='2015-09-23 09:07:55.6796028',
@p12=NULL,@p13=NULL,@p14=NULL,@p15='00:00:00',@p16=0,@p17='00:00:00',
@p18=0,@p19=N'y'
```

Comment: your `Case` entity surely has a `RowVersion` property, this is used for  concurrency check. But when you create a `Case` with `new`, that property ***does not have*** the original value currently stored in database. So the WHERE condition failed, you have to manually set the original values for `RowVersion` with some value fetched from database before calling `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: `dbContext.Cases.Add(newCase)` (it a new object, not an existing one)

Comment: You are trying to update an object that does not exist in the database.

Comment: @StephenMuecke he wants to update an existing row, so I don't think Add would work.

Comment: @Hopeless, Perhaps, but then why is OP initializing a new object?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's another way of updating an existing record. That way he has to use `Attach`. He already said he has that record in database (tried with SQL query directly with `RowVersion` removed).

Comment: @Hopeless, If OP is updating an existing record, then OP should be getting the existing record and updating the appropriate properties, then saving

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, I always do that but maybe he has some reason to do so (the code here may be just some example).

Comment: @Hopeless I also tried selecting the record from the database and then updating it, so the RowVersion field is exactly like it was, but this didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Sean if you tried something new, please add that to your question and also include the generated SQL query. Also the exact exception if thrown should be added.

Comment: @Sean I can see `RowVersion` is still `NULL`. That's the same exception. Is there actually any `RowVersion` in the database table? it should not be null after being loaded from database. It's going to be strange now.

Comment: Yes there is RowVersion in the table. The table is generated with Code First, this way: RowVersion = table.Column<byte[]>(isNullable: true)

Comment: now do you have access to the created database? can you check if the `RowVersion` column has some non-null value? I guess it must be non-null (otherwise the query should have succeeded). If it's non-null, then after being loaded it should have also been non-null. That's why I said it's strange here. For debugging, you can try getting the property entry of `cs.RowVersion` like this `dbContext.Entry(cs).Property("RowVersion")` and see its `OriginalValue`.

Comment: Yes RowVersion is null in the database for the record, and after selecting it I have this in Visual Studio: dbContext.Entry(cs).Property("RowVersion").CurrentValue = null

Comment: if so the query failed reasonably (I was wrong when said the query should have succeeded) - because `RowVersion = NULL` will never be true, it should be `RowVersion is NULL`). But the query is auto-generated so we cannot easily make it be translated to `Is NULL` instead of `= NULL`. However I think you configure the model wrong, the `RowVersion` should not be nullable. Also somehow you should ensure it to be auto-generated whenever a new record is added/modified. I would use `IsRowVersion()` method to configure it.

Comment: In fact I thought it would auto-generate the values of RowVersion. I tried doing RowVersion = new byte[] { 0x20 } when creating a new record, and after this the update worked. But I will try to understand this RowVersion Logic (if I don't add the column, Code First does not create the table). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 14):

Its due to, Primary Key as `Null` value to the `LinQ`.

```
Case newCase = new Case(...);
dbContext.Entry(newCase).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Check your object, does it pass Primary Key `Null`. This Exception is Generally due this reason only.

Comment: That was it! Passing a null value is fine, as long as you configure autoincrement on your DB.

Answer (score 5):

your entity's primary key field means ID is not set.. means it is zero. As you are trying to update record so its ID key should have a value set the ID and update will work. Your update code is fine.

Comment: No the id is set, as I said the condition is WHERE [Id] = p0 and p0 = 1.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I created a new table in SQL and not with any migrations or anything. I forgot to set the `id` field to be a `primary key` and an `identity(1,1)`. Once I put that in place there were no longer any issues saving.

Answer (score 1):

I have table with composite primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
    `Key1` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Value` LONGBLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Key2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Key1`, `Key2`)
)
```

When I try to insert new row with Key2 = 0 it fails with same error.

```
DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
```

My solution is to **avoid saving 0** as key value. It seems to be treated as NULL and cannot be part of valid primary key.
Hope this will save someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I delete the related table and save it ,therefore I had an error .I changed it and I deleted both table at first and then save both of them .