# EF Core 7: "The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); "

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've read quite a few [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735610/entity-framework-update-failure) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67063827/database-operation-expected-to-affect-1-rows-but-actually-affected-0-rows-d) [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230839/c-sharp-entity-framework-core-database-operation-expected-to-affect-1-rows) to this [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153412/why-do-i-have-an-error-the-database-operation-was-expected-to-affect-1-rows), but the use cases differ from mine

I have a new entity (`Bonus`) that I am trying to save. It has two child collections. If I save it WITHOUT the two child collections (`Currencies` and `Tiers`), an `INSERT` statement is generated and the entity is saved correctly.

However, when I add the two collections, I get the above exception and the SQL that is generated is actually trying to `UPDATE` the tables corresponding to those collections when it should be generating an `INSERT`.

Here are the queries generate with and without the child collections:

Without child collections:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Bonus] ([Allocation], [BonusExpiryTerm], [BonusFreeSpinsConvention], [BonusTermsUrl], [BonusValueType], [CasinoId], [DateAdded], [DateEnd], [DateStart], [DateUpdated], [EligibilityDescription], [FreeBetConvention], [Guid], [IsActive], [IsBonusPagePresence], [IsBonusTermsLink], [IsClaimInstructions], [IsExclusive], [IsHighRollerBonus], [IsHomePagePresence], [IsNew], [IsPrimary], [IsPromotionPagePresence], [IsSecondChanceBonus], [IsSpecial], [IsSplitBonusAccountInCashier], [LongDescription], [PrimaryBonusType], [QualityAndEaseOfUse], [SecondaryBonusType], [ShortDescription], [SportsbookBonusTrigger], [SportsbookExcludedBettingTypesAndMarkets], [SportsbookExcludedPaymentMethods], [SportsbookMinimumOddsAllowed], [SportsbookPermittedBettingTypesAndMarkets], [SportsbookPermittedPaymentMethods], [WageringRequirementsDescription], [WageringRequirementsExcludedGamesCsv], [WageringRequirementsIsTrackingReporting], [WageringRequirementsPlayThrough], [WageringRequirementsRequirementsUrl], [WageringRequirementsSignificantTerms], [WageringRequirementsTermsCopy], [WageringRequirementsVipWageringMultiple], [WageringRequirementsVipWageringValue], [WithdrawalRestrictionsAdditionalPenaltyNotes], [WithdrawalRestrictionsAllowLowRiskWagering], [WithdrawalRestrictionsAllowOversizedBets], [WithdrawalRestrictionsBonusAbuseNotes], [WithdrawalRestrictionsDescription], [WithdrawalRestrictionsDisputeResolutionProcess], [WithdrawalRestrictionsDisputeResolutionProcessDescription], [WithdrawalRestrictionsEarlyWithdrawalPenalty], [WithdrawalRestrictionsGamePenalty], [WithdrawalRestrictionsGroupCrossoverPenalty], [WithdrawalRestrictionsGroupCrossoverRestriction], [WithdrawalRestrictionsManagerOverrideClause], [WithdrawalRestrictionsPlayingPatternReview], [WithdrawalRestrictionsReversalOption], [WithdrawalRestrictionsSingleBetLimit], [WithdrawalRestrictionsSlotsDoubleUp], [WithdrawalRestrictionsType], [WithdrawalRestrictionsVideoPokerDoubleUp])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, @p20, @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29, @p30, @p31, @p32, @p33, @p34, @p35, @p36, @p37, @p38, @p39, @p40, @p41, @p42, @p43, @p44, @p45, @p46, @p47,@p48, @p49, @p50, @p51, @p52, @p53, @p54, @p55, @p56, @p57, @p58, @p59, @p60, @p61, @p62, @p63);
SELECT [Id]
FROM [Bonus]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();

',N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 nvarchar(4000),@p4 int,@p5 int,@p6 datetime2(7),@p7 datetime2(7),@p8 datetime2(7),@p9 datetime2(7),@p10 nvarchar(4000),@p11 int,@p12 uniqueidentifier,@p13 bit,@p14 bit,@p15 bit,@p16 bit,@p17 bit,@p18 bit,@p19 bit,@p20 bit,@p21 bit,@p22 bit,@p23 bit,@p24 bit,@p25 bit,@p26 nvarchar(4000),@p27 int,@p28 int,@p29 int,@p30 nvarchar(4000),@p31 int,@p32 nvarchar(4000),@p33 nvarchar(4000),@p34 nvarchar(4000),@p35 nvarchar(4000),@p36 nvarchar(4000),@p37 nvarchar(4000),@p38 nvarchar(4000),@p39 bit,@p40 int,@p41 nvarchar(4000),@p42 nvarchar(4000),@p43 nvarchar(4000),@p44 int,@p45 int,@p46 nvarchar(4000),@p47 int,@p48 int,@p49 nvarchar(4000),@p50 nvarchar(4000),@p51 int,@p52 nvarchar(4000),@p53 int,@p54 int,@p55 int,@p56 int,@p57 int,@p58 int,@p59 int,@p60 int,@p61 int,@p62 int,@p63 int',@p0=0,@p1=NULL,@p2=0,@p3=NULL,@p4=0,@p5=11,@p6='2023-08-15 10:32:27.5650372',@p7=NULL,@p8=NULL,@p9=NULL,@p10=NULL,@p11=NULL,@p12='18EC1B53-FE52-4B6F-BF60-8FB2D0723F79',@p13=0,@p14=0,@p15=0,@p16=0,@p17=0,@p18=0,@p19=0,@p20=0,@p21=0,@p22=0,@p23=0,@p24=0,@p25=0,@p26=NULL,@p27=1,@p28=0,@p29=0,@p30=NULL,@p31=NULL,@p32=NULL,@p33=NULL,@p34=NULL,@p35=NULL,@p36=NULL,@p37=NULL,@p38=NULL,@p39=0,@p40=0,@p41=NULL,@p42=NULL,@p43=NULL,@p44=NULL,@p45=NULL,@p46=NULL,@p47=NULL,@p48=NULL,@p49=NULL,@p50=NULL,@p51=NULL,@p52=NULL,@p53=NULL,@p54=NULL,@p55=NULL,@p56=NULL,@p57=NULL,@p58=NULL,@p59=NULL,@p60=NULL,@p61=NULL,@p62=NULL,@p63=NULL
```

With child collections:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Bonus] ([Allocation], [BonusExpiryTerm], [BonusFreeSpinsConvention], [BonusTermsUrl], [BonusValueType], [CasinoId], [DateAdded], [DateEnd], [DateStart], [DateUpdated], [EligibilityDescription], [FreeBetConvention], [Guid], [IsActive], [IsBonusPagePresence], [IsBonusTermsLink], [IsClaimInstructions], [IsExclusive], [IsHighRollerBonus], [IsHomePagePresence], [IsNew], [IsPrimary], [IsPromotionPagePresence], [IsSecondChanceBonus], [IsSpecial], [IsSplitBonusAccountInCashier], [LongDescription], [PrimaryBonusType], [QualityAndEaseOfUse], [SecondaryBonusType], [ShortDescription], [SportsbookBonusTrigger], [SportsbookExcludedBettingTypesAndMarkets], [SportsbookExcludedPaymentMethods], [SportsbookMinimumOddsAllowed], [SportsbookPermittedBettingTypesAndMarkets], [SportsbookPermittedPaymentMethods], [WageringRequirementsDescription], [WageringRequirementsExcludedGamesCsv], [WageringRequirementsIsTrackingReporting], [WageringRequirementsPlayThrough], [WageringRequirementsRequirementsUrl], [WageringRequirementsSignificantTerms], [WageringRequirementsTermsCopy], [WageringRequirementsVipWageringMultiple], [WageringRequirementsVipWageringValue], [WithdrawalRestrictionsAdditionalPenaltyNotes], [WithdrawalRestrictionsAllowLowRiskWagering], [WithdrawalRestrictionsAllowOversizedBets], [WithdrawalRestrictionsBonusAbuseNotes], [WithdrawalRestrictionsDescription], [WithdrawalRestrictionsDisputeResolutionProcess], [WithdrawalRestrictionsDisputeResolutionProcessDescription], [WithdrawalRestrictionsEarlyWithdrawalPenalty], [WithdrawalRestrictionsGamePenalty], [WithdrawalRestrictionsGroupCrossoverPenalty], [WithdrawalRestrictionsGroupCrossoverRestriction], [WithdrawalRestrictionsManagerOverrideClause], [WithdrawalRestrictionsPlayingPatternReview], [WithdrawalRestrictionsReversalOption], [WithdrawalRestrictionsSingleBetLimit], [WithdrawalRestrictionsSlotsDoubleUp], [WithdrawalRestrictionsType], [WithdrawalRestrictionsVideoPokerDoubleUp])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, @p20, @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29, @p30, @p31, @p32, @p33, @p34, @p35, @p36, @p37, @p38, @p39, @p40, @p41, @p42, @p43, @p44, @p45, @p46, @p47,@p48, @p49, @p50, @p51, @p52, @p53, @p54, @p55, @p56, @p57, @p58, @p59, @p60, @p61, @p62, @p63);
SELECT [Id]
FROM [Bonus]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();

',N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 nvarchar(4000),@p4 int,@p5 int,@p6 datetime2(7),@p7 datetime2(7),@p8 datetime2(7),@p9 datetime2(7),@p10 nvarchar(4000),@p11 int,@p12 uniqueidentifier,@p13 bit,@p14 bit,@p15 bit,@p16 bit,@p17 bit,@p18 bit,@p19 bit,@p20 bit,@p21 bit,@p22 bit,@p23 bit,@p24 bit,@p25 bit,@p26 nvarchar(4000),@p27 int,@p28 int,@p29 int,@p30 nvarchar(4000),@p31 int,@p32 nvarchar(4000),@p33 nvarchar(4000),@p34 nvarchar(4000),@p35 nvarchar(4000),@p36 nvarchar(4000),@p37 nvarchar(4000),@p38 nvarchar(4000),@p39 bit,@p40 int,@p41 nvarchar(4000),@p42 nvarchar(4000),@p43 nvarchar(4000),@p44 int,@p45 int,@p46 nvarchar(4000),@p47 int,@p48 int,@p49 nvarchar(4000),@p50 nvarchar(4000),@p51 int,@p52 nvarchar(4000),@p53 int,@p54 int,@p55 int,@p56 int,@p57 int,@p58 int,@p59 int,@p60 int,@p61 int,@p62 int,@p63 int',@p0=0,@p1=NULL,@p2=0,@p3=NULL,@p4=0,@p5=11,@p6='2023-08-15 10:32:27.5650372',@p7=NULL,@p8=NULL,@p9=NULL,@p10=NULL,@p11=NULL,@p12='18EC1B53-FE52-4B6F-BF60-8FB2D0723F79',@p13=0,@p14=0,@p15=0,@p16=0,@p17=0,@p18=0,@p19=0,@p20=0,@p21=0,@p22=0,@p23=0,@p24=0,@p25=0,@p26=NULL,@p27=1,@p28=0,@p29=0,@p30=NULL,@p31=NULL,@p32=NULL,@p33=NULL,@p34=NULL,@p35=NULL,@p36=NULL,@p37=NULL,@p38=NULL,@p39=0,@p40=0,@p41=NULL,@p42=NULL,@p43=NULL,@p44=NULL,@p45=NULL,@p46=NULL,@p47=NULL,@p48=NULL,@p49=NULL,@p50=NULL,@p51=NULL,@p52=NULL,@p53=NULL,@p54=NULL,@p55=NULL,@p56=NULL,@p57=NULL,@p58=NULL,@p59=NULL,@p60=NULL,@p61=NULL,@p62=NULL,@p63=NULL
go
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [BonusCasinoCurrency] SET [BonusId] = @p64
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [Id] = @p65;
UPDATE [BonusMatchTier] SET [BonusId] = @p66
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [Id] = @p67;
',N'@p65 int,@p64 int,@p67 int,@p66 int',@p65=0,@p64=9435,@p67=0,@p66=9435
go
```

In this case, `@p66=9435` is the correct Id for the next Bonus. I assume the "actually affected 0 row(s);" refers to the `UPDATE` because it updates no rows

The second query block appears to be rolled back and does not insert the bonus.

Here is the EF code:
The `BonusService` and `CasinoService` are where the EF context is accessible.

```
[Test]
public void Create()
{
    BonusMatch bonusMatch = new BonusMatch();

    using (BonusService bonusService = new BonusService())
    using (CasinoService casinoService = new CasinoService())
    {
        Casino casino = casinoService.Find(11, true);
        bonusMatch.Casino = casino;
        bonusMatch.Tiers.Add(new BonusMatchTier(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, "test", "test"));
        bonusMatch.BonusCasinoCurrencies.Add(new BonusCasinoCurrency(casino.AvailableCurrencies.First(), true));

        bonusService.Add(bonusMatch);
    }
    // Assert.Pass();
}
```

You'll notice the AutoMapper `Map` code, This works fine. This is inside `BonusService`

```
public Business.Bonus Add(Business.Bonus dtoBonus)
{
    Domain.Bonus domainBonus = _context.Map<Domain.Bonus>(dtoBonus);

    _context.Add(domainBonus);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    dtoBonus.SetId(domainBonus.Id);

    return dtoBonus;
}
```

EF Model config:

```
    public class CasinoConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Casino>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Casino> modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("TR_upd_Casino"));

            modelBuilder.HasMany(c => c.Bonuses)
                .WithOne(b => b.Casino)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class BonusConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Bonus>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Bonus> modelBuilder)
        {


            #region Bonus Mapping

            modelBuilder.HasDiscriminator(d => d.SecondaryBonusType)
                .HasValue(typeof(BonusMatch), BonusTypes.Match)
                .HasValue(typeof(BonusNoDeposit), BonusTypes.NoDeposit)
                .HasValue(typeof(BonusFreeplay), BonusTypes.Freeplay)
                .HasValue(typeof(BonusPostWager), BonusTypes.PostWager)
                .HasValue(typeof(BonusCashback), BonusTypes.Cashback)
            ;

            modelBuilder
                .HasOne(b => b.Casino)
                .WithMany(c => c.Bonuses)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

             modelBuilder.HasMany(c => c.BonusCasinoCurrencies)
                .WithOne(c => c.Bonus)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
```

In the main model config class

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<BonusMatch>()
                 .OwnsMany(b => b.Tiers,
                     t =>
                     {
                         t.ToTable("BonusMatchTier")
                         .WithOwner(b=> b.Bonus)
                         .HasForeignKey("BonusId");
                     }

                 )
             .Ignore(b => b.HasTiers);
```

My understanding is that EF would know it must `INSERT` those child collections because they belong to a new entity that, itself, is correctly being `INSERTED`.

So why does EF think that these two collections exist and should be `UPDATED` instead of being implicitly new because they exist on a new entity?

UPDATE
As requested, here are the class definitions

```
    public abstract class Bonus : EntityBase
    {
        private IList<BonusCasinoCurrency> _bonusCasinoCurrencies;
        public virtual IList<BonusCasinoCurrency> BonusCasinoCurrencies
        {
            get { return _bonusCasinoCurrencies; }
            set { _bonusCasinoCurrencies = value; }
        }
        public Bonus() : base()
        {
            PrimaryBonusType = PrimaryBonusType.SignUp;
        }



    }



    public class BonusMatch : Bonus
    {
        private List<BonusMatchTier> _tiers;
        public virtual List<BonusMatchTier> Tiers
        {
            get { return _tiers; }
            protected set { _tiers = value; }
        }
        public BonusMatch() : base ()
        {
            _tiers = new List<BonusMatchTier>();
        }

    }
    public class BonusMatchTier 
    {
        public virtual string BonusCode { get; protected set; }
        public virtual decimal MinDepositAmount { get; protected set; }
        public int? FreeSpinsWagering { get; protected set; }
        protected BonusMatchTier() { }

    }
```

Comment: A class model + mappings would help. It's not even clear why the code would generate an `INSERT INTO [Bonus]` statement. Also, we should not have to guess what these services do, esp. whether they share one context instance. Same for the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it to work but I'm not convinced it's the best way to do it - shouldn't EF natively handle the insertion of a new object graph and know how to generate the appropriate SQL for the entire graph? Adding a new object graph with child collections should generate inserts for all entities involved.

Without the two `foreach` loops in my service, which set the child entities' states to `Added`, it seems EF doesn't know they are new and should be inserted rather than updated.

What worked for me was updates in two places - the EF model and in my DataService.

Model change. Note the `Tiers` are commented out. in my opinion, `BonusMatchTiers` **are owned** by a `Bonus` because they cannot exist unless as children of a `Bonus`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BonusMatch>()
//      .OwnsMany(b => b.Tiers,
//          t =>
//          {
//              t.ToTable("BonusMatchTier")
//              .WithOwner(b => b.Bonus)
//              .HasForeignKey("BonusId");
//          }
//      )
    .Ignore(b => b.HasTiers);

// ADDED THIS
modelBuilder.Entity<BonusMatchTier>()
    .ToTable("BonusMatchTier")
    .HasOne(bcc => bcc.Bonus)
    .WithMany(cc => cc.Tiers)
    .HasForeignKey("BonusId")
    .HasConstraintName("FK_BonusMatchTier_BonusMatch")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Then, in the `BonusService` I added the following to inform EF that the child collections were added. I really don't believe this should be necessary. The `Bonus` has many other collections that must be added. (Not to mention the other entities in my model with many child collections!)

```
public Business.Bonus Add(Business.Bonus dtoBonus)
{
    Domain.Bonus domainBonus = _context.Map<Domain.Bonus>(dtoBonus);
    _context.Entry(domainBonus).State = EntityState.Added;

    foreach (Domain.BonusCasinoCurrency bcc in domainBonus.BonusCasinoCurrencies)
    {
        _context.BonusCasinoCurrencies.Attach(bcc);
        _context.Entry(bcc).State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    foreach (Domain.BonusMatchTier bmt in ((Domain.BonusMatch)domainBonus).Tiers)
    {
        _context.BonusMatchTiers.Attach(bmt);
        _context.Entry(bmt).State = EntityState.Added;
    }


    _context.Add(domainBonus);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    dtoBonus.SetId(domainBonus.Id);
    return dtoBonus;
}
```

So this does work and the correct `INSERT` statements are generated, but there **has to be*** a better way